# What is a Sonic Wall?

Tags: firewalls

I found an old box in my garage and it contains a 'sonicwall' device. It looks like a huge router but I am unsure what it does. Do I hook it up between my modem and router and it somehow provides secure protection?

What is it and what is its purpose?

Also, what protection does it provide?

Comment: [Sonic Wall](http://lmgtfy.com/?q=Sonic+Wall)

Comment: Is there a model number?

Answer (score 1):

SonicWall is a company, now owned by Dell, that makes security appliances.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SonicWall

I am fairly certain you can find the specifics for any device you own on Dell's website or at sonicwall.com.